I have a csv file with data , The Data repeats depending upon different time and different amount . I want to group same kind of numbers together

INPUT
column 1     column 2.     column 3
a            jim            50
b            tim            60
c            jim            10
d            vel.           20
e            tim            30
f            vel            20
g            hem             55
h.           hem              40

OUTPUT
a --   jim. -- 50
c --   jim  -- 10

b --   tim. -- 60
e --   tim  -- 30

d --   vel --  20
f --   vel --  20

g --   hem --  55
h.--   hem --  40



What have you tried? Stackoverflow can help you, but you need to show your effort.

You are not very clear about what you mean by "grouping together"
